# Handle HTML and JS request based on javascripts on/off in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When user turn off JavaScript then follow HTML request flow otherwise follow JS request flow.

- HTML flow means : request as html => render html template => response as HTML ( when JavaScript off in browser )
- JS flow means : request as JS => render JS template => response as JS ( when JavaScript on in browser )

**I have one solution for that and that is :-**

- I have to write code to handle both request in my all controller something like this :

  ```
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
  end
  ```
- I have to create both type of template js and html and render common data in it.

But in above solution, i think there is very much duplicate code like we have to write respond_to code in every controller and we have to create two copy of every page (js.html, erb.html).

So i need standard solution(if any) to handle both kind of request based on JavaScript enabled/disable in browser without any duplication.

Comment: you can use partials and call them inside the Html and the Js templates

Comment: @AbdooDev, i already said that i don't want to create html, js template for each and every page. I think it's not good practice to create two copy(html, js) of every page.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create this block for methods that need to respond to js calls - normally these are ajax methods, and not every method in your application.

Are you really doing everything in your application by ajax? Or just a select few methods?

Comment: I want to use ajax for almost 40% to 45%  methods from my application . So, i don't want to create two copy of file for every page for almost 40% to 45% methods.

Comment: But you have to... if you have a page that you want to respond to js, *and* you want it to degrade gracefully to html, then you have to implement both pages. You can use partials and shared code to reduce duplication but you can't avoid doing it.

Comment: Ok then there is no way to do this, right ?
but what if we open form in modal in js request and open same form as HTML request ? Then i need to redesign form in HTML request and need to duplicate code, right ?

Comment: In a situation like that, the majority of the form would be inside a partial, and your html page would simply render that partial. Your js response would render the partial into a receiving element and show that element. There isn't any duplication there since all the common code is in a partial anyway.